# Host-only VirtualBox vboxnet1 IP belongs to host

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to connect to a server running on a guest OS in VirtualBox. VirtualBox is configured to assign a static IP to the guest. However I'm pretty sure that the IP it assigns actually belongs to the host. If I have an nginx server running on the host then requests to the vboxnet1 IP are intercepted by the host serve and never reach the guest.

Both the host and guest are Debian.

Also, I get the same result with and without the VirtualBox DHCP server enabled.

Here's the VirtualBox network settings (can't embed images with <10 rep...sigh):

[image]

And the VM network settings:

[image]

I've also tried with different IP addresses for the host, no change.

ifconfig on host:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:f5:e8:b0:e0  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:183363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:183363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:70022881 (70.0 MB)  TX bytes:70022881 (70.0 MB)

vboxnet1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:01  
          inet addr:192.168.66.1  Bcast:192.168.66.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2545 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:308371 (308.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:fd:52:c0:1b:b1  
          inet addr:192.168.2.106  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::26fd:52ff:fec0:1bb1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11724555 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7429276 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:16204472393 (16.2 GB)  TX bytes:1222715861 (1.2 GB)
```

iptables on host:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
[sudo] password for aidan: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Here's an nmap comparing the host IP and the 'guest' IP:

```
$ nmap 192.168.66.1

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-07-22 13:28 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.66.1
Host is up (0.00015s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
902/tcp  open  iss-realsecure
3128/tcp open  squid-http
5050/tcp open  mmcc

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.16 seconds

$ nmap 192.168.2.106

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-07-22 13:28 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.106
Host is up (0.00015s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
902/tcp  open  iss-realsecure
3128/tcp open  squid-http
5050/tcp open  mmcc

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.17 seconds
```

Comment: Have you tried doing ifconfig inside the vm?

Comment: It's a VM from vulnhub.com, can't get onto the box the usual way :) This one: https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/tophatsec-zorz,117/

Comment: In case there is a static IP assigned already to the guest. Then probably having vboxnet1 of 192.168.66.1 is not good. Better assign it 192.168.0.1

Comment: I tried assigning it 192.168.0.1 and as it boots up it says 'Waiting for network configuration...'. And then same deal as before. The VM notes say that DHCP service is enabled  and that an IP address will be automaticalled assigned...not sure whether they're referring to the VirtualBox DHCP server or not though :/